# How does garlic preparation affect its active compounds or medicinal properties?

Tags: biochemistry, vegetable

I read the following claims about how to consume garlic:

- Consume immediately after crushing since the active compounds (allicin) is volatile and gets oxidized as soon as it's crushed
- Allow to sit 10 minutes after crushing to allow time for allicin to form
- Do not change the PH of garlic (i.e. mix with acid/lemon) in order not to disrupt the formation of allicin, during those 10 minutes
- Allicin is completely lost within 20 minutes after crushing

If so:

1. Which of those claims is true? Is the wait-10-minutes practice is only recommended before heating the garlic? i.e. should you wait at all after crushing, when you consume it raw? (e.g. in a salad)
2. Given this is how I prepare a salad:

   Cut vegetables and herbs

   Crush garlic and mix in (no waiting)

   Add lemon juice and vinegar and mix right away

   Season with salt and pepper

   Pour olive oil and mix right away

   Let sit refrigerated in air-tight container 5-10 minutes

   The salad is consumed at least 15 minutes after garlic is crushed, and it takes me another 15 minutes to finish eating the salad

   By that time (30 min after crushing) are the active compounds in the garlic (particularly allicin) preserved or completely lost?
3. Will it make any difference if I mix the garlic in the oil first (to merely prevent oxidation), wait 10 minutes, mix in the acid, and pour everything over the salad right before serving?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Biology in terms of SE Biology. You might try SE Nutrition as there doesn't appear to be a SE Quack Medicine.

Comment: @David I couldn't find SE Nutrition board, were you referring to SE Medical Sciences?

Comment: @David - that comment :D

Comment: Contrary to David's comment, there is no nutrition SE site. I inquired over at MedSci if this is ontopic there, but unfortunately not. Over here I see it as offtopic as it's more about the chemical properties of a compound. I've asked over at Chemistry. After that, I've ran out of ideas I'm afraid.

Comment: I doubt it would remain open on chemistry.se (I am a mod there, cc @AliceD). The question basically boils down to *how is allicin formed when crushing garlic, and how stable is it after that*, which is basically already answered on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allicin). (Questions about properties of compounds should be accompanied with the necessary literature research.) The other, principle, problem is that the conditions are probably producing a much larger uncertainty than you would be able to measure in the levels of Allicin, and all would not be reproducible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's offtopic here as it's not a biological problem, but one of nutrition and chemical stability. I've inquired across the network, but unfortunately I can't find a suitable place, as mods of other sites have rejected it. Apologies.